# Парсинг сохранённого состояния веб-страниц встроенного WebView вручную

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

Есть `WebView`, состояние которого сохраняется в методе `onSaveInstanceState` и восстанавливается в `onRestoreInstanceState` в `Activity` примерно следующим образом:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    //...
    webView.saveState(outState);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //...
    webView.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Если вызвать метод `WebView#restoreState` и передать этот `Bundle`, то `WebView` спарсит состояние, поймёт его и применит к `WebView`. Мне известно, что в этом `Bundle` сохраняется blob (значение типа `byte[]`) по ключу `WEBVIEW_CHROMIUM_STATE`. В этом состоянии хранится URL веб-страницы, куки, позиция прокрутки, и некоторые другие подобные данные.

А как можно самостоятельно спарсить данные из blob'а по ключу `WEBVIEW_CHROMIUM_STATE` из этого `Bundle`? Нигде не нашёл документацию, как можно с ним работать, как парсить, объект какого вообще типа представляет собой этот blob, может, какой-то `Serializable`... В исходном коде SDK также не удалось найти ничего полезного ввиду огромного количества уровней абстракции.

Вот пример, как выглядит blob в `Bundle` состояния `WebView` в текстовом виде для главной веб-страницы Яндекса:

[image: blob]

Comment: WebView поставляется отдельно в виде приложения и построена на ядре chromium. Исходники нужно искать не в SDK, а здесь:  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD. Но я бы не советовал - сильно подозреваю что от версии к версии формат сейва может меняться, придётся изучать все изменения, ветвиться по версиям в коде и при любом обновлении компонента [`Android System WebView`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.webview&hl=ru&gl=US) ваш парсер может перестать его понимать.